# Autocomplete in laravel from database

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete, typeahead

In laravel I am trying to implement autocomplete.

In my view i have a textbox

```
  <input class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Search by Name, City or Zip Code" type="text"  name='query_string'>
```

Script for autocomplete is

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({


    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
    }
});
```

And my controller function is as follows

```
   public function autocomplete(Request $request)
   {
     $data = User::select("*")
       ->where([["name","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%"]])
       ->orWhere("building_address","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
       ->get();
     return response()->json($data);
}
```

Autocomplete is working fine and showing the results from database if a match in occur with name. How can i display the both name and address in the search box. Please help.